# clean reinstall of "everything" (i.e. homebrew, rvm, rails, xcode) on OSX. Just reinstall osx?

Tags: macos, rvm, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I've been getting some errors (misplaced files, wrong versions of things, etc.) in my terminal that should not be appearing by default and I just want to set up from scratch everything I use for development so that I can work on a clean slate.

Should I just reinstall OSX using the "Recovery" tool? Is this enough? Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Edit: Reinstalled OSX with the recovery tool, didn't change anything...

Comment: Why don't you post the errors, maybe it's something simple we can help you fix.